# How to visualise in a bar chart the proportion of the distribution of a variable between factors in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this simple data frame:

```
gender  likes_received
male      500
female   1000
```

and I want to create a bar chart (with a single bar) where it shows the distribution of the likes_received between the genders. I want to use ggplot but I can't seem to find a way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added a "foo" value so that there is an x-axis

```
library(tidyverse)

data.frame(gender=c('male', 'female'), 
       likes_received = c(500, 1000), 
       foo='1') %>% 
    ggplot(aes(foo, likes_received, fill=gender)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

Comment: `geom_col` would do the same but you won't have to add that `stat="identity"`. If you want shares instead of counts, add `geom_col(position = position_fill())`